# Django custom count based on ORM filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am trying to gather additional information based on previously filtered data, like this

```
count(distinct batch_id) as batches,
sum(files) as files
```

The result is influenced by the previous filtering eg.

```
.filter(batch_id__gte=165)
```

I tried to clone the QuerySet and annotate aboves SQL

```
.annotate(
        batches=Count('batch_id', distinct=True),
        batch_files=Sum('files')
    )
```

but this doesn't work because then the SQL is appended to the existing SELECT query

Is there an easy way of getting a second query with a custom SELECT part while keeping the WHERE part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to [**`aggregate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) instead, like:

```
result = Model.objects.filter(batch_id__gte=165).aggregate(
    batches=Count('batch_id', distinct=True),
    batch_files=Sum('files')
)
```

`result` is then a dictionary that contains two keys: `'batches'` and `'batch_files'` that contain the `Count('batch_id', distinct=True)` and `Sum('files')` respectively.

Annotating means that you will calculate properties, *per object*, not over the entire queryset, whereas *aggregating* means you calculate the aggregate over the entire (filtered) queryset.